# mvc controller returning raw html instead of the normal view

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-4, tabs, html.dropdownlistfor

**Last Edit**
After hours spent googling, it turns out that bootstrap tab and server-validation do not play along. Thank you guys for the help.

**Edit**
The culprit is the repopulation of the selectlistitem.  I am presented with a catch-22:
 
- remove the repopulation of the selectlistitem == error in view (null reference).
- add the repopulation of the selectlistitem == raw html.
Have anybody experience this issue?

I am experiencing something weird, I think.  My controller is returning a raw html instead of a normal view when !modelstate.isvalid.
The GET:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult AddNewProduct()
    {
        ...
        return View(productVM);
    }
```

The Post:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult AddNewProduct(ProductVM prodVM, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> images)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ...
        }
        else
        {
            //repopulate dropdownlistfor
            prodVM.slCategory = GetCategory(prodVM.prodDetailVM.storeID);
            prodVM.selectedCat = 0;
            prodVM.slAuctionType = GetAuctionType();
            return View(prodVM);
        }
    }
```

The dropdownlist is a cascading type.
Can anybody give me a hint as to what is wrong?  I have googled with no success.  Thx.

**Edit**
I am not sure if the View is the problem, it renders ok on load, but displaying raw html on model not valid.

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to be in the controller itself. Can you share your view markup?

Comment: post your view here there are no problem in controller side

Comment: were you using layout?

Comment: @LittleDragon view posted.

Comment: @ManojKumawat Yes, I am using layout -- see the newly posted View